# NSApplicationPresentationHideDock has no effect

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have a window that I want to be able to take fullscreen without allowing access to the dock or the menu bar.

I am enabling fullscreen support by setting the window collection behavior to `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary`. I have tried setting the collection behavior in both IB and by calling `setCollectionBehavior:` directly and it has no effect on the issue.

My window delegate also responds to `window:willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions:` returning the options `NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen | NSApplicationPresentationHideDock | NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar`

The window has the fullscreen button available in the titlebar and moves in and out of fullscreen mode just fine so I know I have setup the fullscreen support correctly.

The menu bar behaves exactly as it is supposed to based on the presentation options I provide.

The dock how ever is a different story, it is always acting as if I passed the auto hide option and will slide into view when I move the mouse to the bottom of the screen no matter what option I provide in `window:willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions:`

It is really odd as I get a hidden menu bar with an auto hide dock, and if you were to return this equivalent combination of flags (`NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideDock | NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar`) in `window:willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions:` you get an exception saying that combination is not valid.

Am I missing something?

**Update 1:**

Tried this on OS X 10.8 and it works just as the docs indicate it should. On OS X 10.9 and OS X 10.10 it fails every time. Also tried Apple's sample code project "FullScreenWindow" it specifies the flags just as I do and it also fails to hide the dock on 10.9 and 10.10, works perfect on 10.8.

I think this may be an Apple bug, either a problem with the feature or, if they deprecated the feature it is a documentation bug since that is not indicated anywhere.

I have logged it with Apple.

**Update 2:**

Found the solution!

it seems you must not only provide the windows presentation options. But it seems the application has its own presentation options that will override the windows options.

Added this to my window delegate and everything works.

```
- (void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setPresentationOptions:NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar | NSApplicationPresentationHideDock];
}

- (void)windowDidExitFullScreen:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setPresentationOptions:NSApplicationPresentationDefault];

}
```

Comment: maybe either menubar or dock most be available?

Comment: The docs say that having both hidden, having the dock hidden and menu bar auto hide, and having both auto hide are valid options, and I have seen many other apps that have that behavior. I'm sure I am just missing something but I can't figure out what that might be.

Comment: On 10.10.3 it works until you cmd-tab back & forth to fullscreened app. After that, Dock and menubar start to auto-appear again. Darn!

Comment: Is the bug report with Apple still open? I don't suppose there's an OpenRadar ticket about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

it seems you must not only provide the windows presentation options. But it seems the application has its own presentation options that will override the windows options.

Added this to my window delegate and everything works.

```
- (void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setPresentationOptions:NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar | NSApplicationPresentationHideDock];
}

- (void)windowDidExitFullScreen:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setPresentationOptions:NSApplicationPresentationDefault];

}
```

Comment: I'm using 10.10 and don't get the full screen button in the title bar.  How did you get that?  I can get the window to zoom to full screen on launch and toggle the zoom from a Main Menu View menuItem that I added.  Your additional code prevents accessing the Main menu.  BTW, neither iPhoto nor Safari have a zoom button, zoom is accessed from a Main Menu View menuItem too.

Comment: The problem rises when the user is playing with focus - e.g. he summons a mission control - then the app returns to its default presentation options - which is bad IMO

Comment: And setting the app’s presentationOptions outside of will enter full screen seems to have the original effect with autohide dock :(

Comment: Ok found out that hooking in to applicationDidChangeOcclusionState gives all the feedback events for Reveal feature.